# How to display Integer value returned from class on to the NStextField?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-yosemite

Here,I attached image which will show my code,I am trying to access value from class in objective-c and trying to displaying on `NSTextField`

Comment: where is the image or sample code?

Comment: It's hard to read.Please post codes correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because NSInteger will transform to 32-bit and 64-bit with CPU bit changes.You can use this to avoid this:

```
NSLog(@"Your integer: %ld", (long)txt1.integerValue);
```

Or you can ignore these errors because it doesn't matter.

Comment: thanks buddy,,it's right but if i replace the int variable to NSString then also i faced same problem.

Comment: @user5789296 you should use %@ for instance variable.

Comment: i attached another screen shot of my code,in which i tried to display nsstring    on nstextfield but value not displayed on the screen , & also tried to trace it through NSLog